# How to run docker container in a remote machine

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run this jenkins pipeline code via DOCKER. I am using AWS ec2-user as a VM here. **This code is working fine**, but...

```
node{
 stage('SCM CHECKOUT'){
   git 'https://bitbucket.org/rajesh212/myapp.git'    
   }
 stage('MVN BUILD'){
   def mvnHome = tool name: 'maven', type: 'maven'
   sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean package"
   }
stage('DEPLOYMENT VIA DOCKER'){
   def customImage = docker.build("image:${env.BUILD_ID}")
   docker.image("image:${env.BUILD_ID}").withRun('-p 9090:8080'){sleep 10000}
   }
```

1. If I am not giving sleep command then this job ran
   successfully but my docker container start and stop immediately. i.e
   I am not able to get the output. How to solve this problem?
2. I want to run this docker image on a remote machine? how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to run on a remote server, you must use the `withServer` [command](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-a-remote-docker-server).

As for the container stopping, try changing the `withRun` command to `withRun('-d -p 9090:8080')`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using declarative pipelines, try this ssh command. As a prerrequisite you need to set up a key pair to allow Jenkins to ssh into the remote server. An specific ssh key pair for deployment is recommended for security issues:

```
stage('Deploy to Production') {
      steps{
        sh 'ssh -i path/to/deploy_private_key user@DNS_REMOTE_SERVER "docker run -d REGISTRY/YOUR_DOCKER_IMAGE:TAG"' 
      }
}
```

Use the -d parameter to run the container in detached mode.
Hope it helps.